# Symfony2 registered MySQL soundex fails?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

The attempt to register the soundex function results in:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 106: Error: Expected end of string, got
>   'SOUNDEX'

#### Class definition:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;

/**
 * SoundexFunction ::= "SOUNDEX" "(" StringPrimary  ")"
 */
class SoundexFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    public $stringExpression = null;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->$stringExpression = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);

    }
    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'SOUNDEX(' .
            $this->$stringExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) .
        ')';
    }
}
```

#### config.yml snippet:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
      default:
        auto_mapping: true
        dql:
          string_functions:
            soundex: Mana\ClientBundle\DQL\SoundexFunction
```

#### query function:

```
protected function getMatches($incoming) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $fname = $incoming['fname'];
    $sname = $incoming['sname'];
    $sql = "select id, active, fname, sname, dob, phys_addr, phys_city
        from ManaClientBundle:Client where SOUNDEX(fname) = SOUNDEX(:fname) and
        SOUNDEX(sname) = SOUNDEX(:sname)
        order by sname, fname";
    $query = $em->createQuery($sql)
        ->setParameters(array(
            'fname' => $fname,
            'sname' => $sname,
        ));
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Comment: You'd probably get an error if it didn't match, but how come your class name doesn't match your definition in config?

Comment: @Mike: Good point/catch!!  Edited above to show fix, but it doesn't change outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geo, not sure why it's not working for you.  I tried it with the QueryBuilder and it worked.  However, I did have to replace your usages of `$this->$stringExpression` with `$this->stringExpression`.

Edit:

I just tested your code in a bare application, and the issue isn't in the SOUNDEX, it's in your SQL.  Try assigning an SQL alias to your entity:

```
$sql = "select client.id, client.active, client.fname, client.sname, client.dob, client.phys_addr, client.phys_city
        from ManaClientBundle:Client client where SOUNDEX(client.fname) = SOUNDEX(:fname) and
        SOUNDEX(client.sname) = SOUNDEX(:sname)
        order by client.sname, client.fname";
```

Comment: Fascinating.  Even after correcting my dopey syntax it still fails.  I've added the query function above, just in case...

Comment: Debugger shows that parser knows that custom string function [soundex] exists, so registration is effective.  Yet it still throws error shown above.  There must be some other not-yet-revealed criteria to make this function work!

Comment: Brilliant!  That's what I get for simply copying a SQL statement.  Note to self - Doctrine requires an alias.  Maybe I should get one, too!  Thanks, Mike.